# send pings NOT in the main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, ping

I want to send pings with multiples threads.

I'm using simplePingHelper:
https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper/

that used simplePing of apple implementation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing

The pings in the main thread works well, but when I tried to do it in background thread it's call to the right ping's methods but the ping not happen. it's arrive to this line:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(endTime) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; // This timeout is what retains the ping helper
```

and that's it.

How can I do it?

EDITED:
I tried to run it like following code:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [SimplePingHelper ping:@"x.x.x.x" target:self sel:@selector(pingResult:)];
        });
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to run the code on a background thread? Update your  question with relevant details and code.

Comment: What do you mean by a "background thread". Explain what you did to make the thread a background one.

Answer (score 0):

SimplePing (and its users) do(es) not support even being started from background-thread.

If you really need to keep main-thread clean, use instead:
https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBPing

> **Note** that the linked repo's author explicitly mentions SimplePing issues.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball No, but if I make a PR someday, does that count?

Comment: eh I personally don't think that's really worth mentioning. But you might then say you've helped contribute to the project before.